# Greenplum-Spark Connector generate too many external table

Tags: apache-spark, greenplum

I'm programming with Greenplum-Spark Connector, and I find that every time I use Spark to take the table data, an external table is created in Greenplum and is not deleted after taking data. When i query the same table, another external been generated. Can anybody tell me  if the extenral table can be used in the future? Will this table be automatically cleaned?

Comment: Temporary external tables should be cleaned up after your spark job finishes. What version of the connector are you using?

Comment: greenplum-spark_2.11-1.7.0.jar  or greenplum-spark_2.11-1.6.2 on spark-2.4.4 have same problem.

Comment: Tables will get cleaned up automatically after your spark job session is closed. It is possible that if the job fails, tables might not get cleaned up.

Comment: We are planning a feature that uses TEMPORARY external tables. This would guarantee external table cleanup. The feature will most likely be released in version 2.1.0 of the Spark Connector (in about 1 - 2 months).
`If specified, creates a temporary readable or writable external table definition in Greenplum Database. Temporary external tables exist in a special schema; you cannot specify a schema name when you create the table. Temporary external tables are automatically dropped at the end of a session.`

Comment: Thank  frankgh! your reply help me a lot and look forward to the release of 2.1.0. My application scenario is through spark cross-database query. When the query is completed, the program sometimes does not automatically exit. At this time, the program needs to be killed. This may be the reason why the external table cannot be cleared. What confuses me is that every query of the same table needs to recreate the external table. Is it possible to reuse the external table?Or will there be any problems with dropping the external table after completed query?

Comment: the spark connector version 2.1.0 has been released and it addresses the issue above.